# Ito vs Stratonovich SDE with irregular time-dependence in coefficients

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose I am interested in the Stratonovich SDE
$$ dX_t = b(t,X_t) dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \circ dB_t $$
If the coefficients are smooth enough in time and space, I can show this is equivalent to the Ito SDE
$$ dX_t = \left[ b(t,X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma(t,X_t) \sigma'(t,X_t) \right] dt + \sigma(t,X_t)  dB_t $$
where $'$ denotes derivative in the space variable

I show this by using the definition of Stratonovich integral for two continuous semimartingales, given in terms of the Ito integral
$$ \int_0^T Y_s \circ dZ_s = \int_0^T Y_s dZ_s + \frac{1}{2} [Y,Z]_T $$
To make this conversion in the SDE example, I have to calculate to be able to compute the covariation $[\sigma(\cdot, X_{\cdot}), B]_t$ which is easy because I can expand $\sigma(t, X_{t})$ using Ito's formula.

**In the case where $\sigma(t,x)$ is smooth in $x$ but say only Holder continuous in $t$, then I cannot expand $\sigma(t, X_{t})$ using Ito's formula. But, I think the equivalence of the Ito and Stratonovich formulations should still hold true. Does it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.

> Let $dX_t = b(t,X_t) \, dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \, dB_t$ be an Itô process. Let $\Phi=\Phi(t,x)$ be such that $\Phi(\cdot,x)$ is continuous, $\Phi(t,\cdot)$ continuously differentiable, $$\mathbb{E}\int_0^T |\Phi(t,X_t)^2 | \, dt < \infty.$$ Then $$\int_0^T \Phi(t,X_t) \, \circ dB_t = \int_0^T \Phi(t,X_t) \, dB_t + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Phi(t,X_t) \cdot \sigma(t,X_t) \, dt$$

cf. *R.L. Stratonovich: A new representation for stochastic integrals and equations*.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, but the $X$ from the question is *not* an Itō process.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well, this depends very much on your definition of a "Itô process".... In my answer I simply assume that $X_t$ solves the SDE $dX_t = b(t,X_t) \, dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \, dB_t$; that's it.

Comment: That's what I mean, the OP assumed that $X_t$ solves $dX_t = b(t,X_t) dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \circ dB_t$, not $dX_t = b(t,X_t) dt + \sigma(t,X_t) dB_t$

Comment: I don't want to advertise [my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368414/equivalence-of-it%c5%8d-and-stratonovich-equations-and-how-we-ensure-that-the-latter) here, but maybe you can take a look at it. It targets the same issue as here.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see your point. Unfortunately I can't really help you with your question; you might want to take a look at the paper "Stratonovich stochastic differential equations driven by general semimartingales" by Kurtz, Pardoux & Protter (... if I remember correctly, it's rather "readable").